# Concisely finding rows from less than 6 months ago in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to find entries in my table from between 6 months ago and today. Here's the query that I'm currently running:

```
WHERE (DATE(l.date_fin) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH)) AND CURDATE())
```

However, it doesn't look right to me: it feels like there's a more concise and/or faster way to get the same results as this query. Is there any such way?

Comment: Can there be entries where date_fin is later than today? If not, you could try the following: DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH) <= l.date_fin;

Answer (score 14):

This should be enough to get what you want:

```
WHERE l.date_fin > CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH;
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT l.date_fin FROM table WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,l.date_fin,NOW()) < 6
```

Answer (score 1):

easy way to do this is:

```
WHERE DATE(l.date_fin) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE;
```

if you have index on column `date_fin` then to get the best performance you can use:

```
WHERE l.date_fin BETWEEN CAST(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AS DATETIME) AND
    DATE_SUB(CAST(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS DATETIME), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT l.date_fin FROM table WHERE l.date_fin between current_date and  current_date+interval -6 month
```